# vscode red wavy underline just pops up and auto completion stop work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[auto completion stop working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5baz.png)

[red wavy underline pops up from nowhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42RRq.png)

All things are good when I start working. But it just goes wrong suddenly that the red wavy underline pops up and cannot be removed, even if I deleted all my code and the line is still there. As you can see and auto completion stop working that the "print" didn't show when I typed "pri". Is there anyone possibly know how to fix this up? Appreciate.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio Code?

Comment: what does the red squiggle tell you (on hover)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your language server has broken down, you can open the `Python Language Server` channel in the `OUTPUT` pannel for more information.

You can try to restart the VSCode to restart the language server. If it still does not work, you can try to switch the python language server in the settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

[image]